# Hensel's lemma for the completion of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$

Tags: number-theory, function-fields, hensels-lemma

If we want to find the roots of a polynomial $f(x)$ modulo a prime $p$ to the power of $n$, we can use Hensel's lemma. Let's say we want to find all roots of $x^3+x^2+4x+1$ mod $49$. Then we can use Hensel's lemma for p-adic integers and compute the roots only mod $7$.

Is there also a version of Hensel's lemma, not only for the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, but for the completion of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$? Or exists any other root lifting technique in this case? I didn't found anything so far...

Comment: Sure. Let $f(X) \in \mathbb{F}_q[[t]][X]$, $q$ an odd prime power. Hensel lemma is just saying that if for $a_k \in \mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$, $f(a_k) \equiv 0 \bmod t^k \mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$ then $f(a_k+bt^{k}) = f(a_k)+b t^{k} f'(a_k) +O(t^{2k})$ so if $f'(a_k) \equiv f'(a_1) \not\equiv 0 \bmod t  \mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$ then you can always choose $a_{k+1} = a_k + b t_{k}, b \equiv - \frac{f(a_k)}{t^{k} f'(a_1)} \bmod t \mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$ such that $f(a_{k+1}) \equiv 0 \bmod t^{k+1}\mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$, moreover the obtained limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k$ is the unique lift of $a_1$.

Comment: Sounds good, but what do you mean with mod $...\mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$? In the case of the p-adic integers I only look at mod $p$ and not $p \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: With $\mathbb{Z}_p$ it works the same way replacing $t, \mathbb{F}_q[[t]]$ by $p, \mathbb{Z}_p$. My comment applies to any complete DVR whose uniformizer satisfies $(a+b\pi^k)^n = a^n+b\pi^k n a^{n-1}+O(\pi^{k+1})$